# Accessibility with screen-readers and JavaScript focus events?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a form that has some JavaScript to advance to the next field when valid text is entered (sample below). My question is how is this handled by a screen-reader. Will this confuse the reader or will it detect the change in focus and read the new field out to the user?

**HTML**

```
<form action="/some/action" method="post" role="form">
    <legend>A Form</legend>
    <label for="first_number">First Number</label>
    <input id="first_number" name="first_number" required type="text" value="">
    <label for="second_number">Second Number</label>
    <input id="second_number" name="second_number" required type="text" value="">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function (document, window) {
    function getFocusCallback(current_focus, go) {
        var check = document.getElementById(current_focus);
        var el = document.getElementById(go);
        var pat = new RegExp('^\\d{3}$');
        return function callback() {
            if (pat.test(check.value)) {
                el.focus();
            }
        };
    }

    document.getElementById('first_number').addEventListener('input', getFocusCallback('first_number', 'second_number'));
})(document, window);
```

So after the user has entered three digits in the first field, the focus method is called on the second.

Comment: As far as I know when `.focus()` occurs then they all take the callback and basically run `document.activeElement` so by running `.focus()` (as a11y standard) there's no need for aria atomic or other live change stuff because they're all already using it as an active element indicator whenever it's invoked via tabbing for example or manually invoking via `.focus()` but left as comment since I'm not 100% positive about **all** screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue here is ***unexpected behavior***. For non-sighted users, any non-standard behavior could be a possible source of confusion, since it would work differently than every other website.

Also, is this a feature that you'd have on every field, or just some of them? If you have multiple fields with different behavior, that would be especially confusing.

There was a pretty good thread about this a couple of years ago with input from several people way more knowledgeable than myself.
https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/w3c-wai-ig/2015AprJun/0162.html

You'll need to click the "*Next message*" link at the bottom of each page to read all messages in the thread.

Comment: Thanks, the link was helpful and also got me thinking about other accessibility issues. In particular, issues of mobility. While not related to screen-readers, wrong key presses from users with mobility issues become much more difficult with auto-tab. I still feel like I am in the dark as far as screen-readers go. Documentation is sparse and there is little information on the screen reader experience from actual users.

Comment: There are several free screen readers that you can work with. I'd recommend NVDA used in combination with FireFox or IE. If you're on a Mac, VoiceOver is also pretty good for a free tool.